# terraform.tfvars file: why variable block is required

Tags: terraform

I have created the following terraform.tfvars file:

```
ec2_image = "ami-00035f41c82244dab"
ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
```

And use it as follows in a main.tf file:

```
resource "aws_instance" "OneServer" {
    ami             =       "${var.ec2_image}"
    instance_type   =       "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
}
```

Then I execute the 'terraform plan' command and it complains with:

> Error: resource 'aws_instance.OneServer' config: unknown variable
>   referenced: 'ec2_image'; define it with a 'variable' block

So I changed the main.tf file as follows:

```
variable "ec2_image" {}
variable "ec2_instance_type" {}

resource "aws_instance" "OneServer" {
    ami             =       "${var.ec2_image}"
    instance_type   =       "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
}
```

Then the command 'terraform plan' works OK.

I don't understand why these variable blocks are required. What's the point for it?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable

Comment: I know that, looked through it obviously. But where is it mentioned that -when usin tfvars file- the variable block is still required in the tf file. I fully understand that the variable block is required when using tf variable file, but not when a tfvars variable file is used.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your follow up question but the link @MattSchuchard posted explains it. You must define all input variables in the linked syntax (optionally including defaults and/or types) and then if you want you can override/set the values of these by using a number of options including a tfvars file or passing the var through the CLI or using `TF_VAR_` environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using the `-var-file` command-line switch?

For example, I don't use that switch - I just define my overridable variables in a random `tf` file (named in my case `variable.tf`).  If the `-var-file` switch is not used, that means the `variable` block is required to tell Terraform when a variable is being defined.

Comment: `-var-file` is for passing tfvars style files that are not automatically loaded by Terraform (`terraform.tfvars` or `*.auto.tfvars`)b so this doesn't answer the question.